# Error durring wxWidget application linking

Tags: c++, codeblocks, wxwidgets

I am trying to compile a simple wxWidgets application using Code::Blocks.

I have built the wxWidgets 3.1.3 from source and added the /wxWidgets/lib/gcc_dll/ directory to the linker search path. But the problem is I get error:

```
cannot find -lwxmsw31_core

cannot find -lwxbase31
```

Is there a known solution for this?

Thank you.

Comment: Where are the files `libwxmsw31_core.a` and `libwxbase31.a`? These are the files that the linker will actually look for.

Comment: The problem is I dont know where this files are. They seem to be absent.

Comment: Use the wxWidgets project wizard in Code::Blocks to create a new wxWidgets project.  The wizard will set up all of the include folders, lib folders, link libraries, and compiler definitions you need.

Comment: How did you build wxWidgets from sources? Notably, did you build it as shared/dynamic library? If you did, and if the build succeeded, the libraries in questions really ought to be under the `lib/gcc_dll` subdirectory, so if you don't have them there, something must have gone wrong and you need to check your build logs.